# "Они пошли(,) кто на поле, а кто на торговлю" — что за синтаксическая конструкция?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

*Они пошли, **кто на поле, а кто на торговлю**.*

*Кто на поле, а кто на торговлю* - это уточняющая или присоединительная конструкция?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Они пошли кто на поле, а кто на торговлю.**

Это вариант наречного выражения ***кто куда***: Они пошли кто куда.

Соответственно, это простое предложение с однородными обстоятельствами.

Из словаря Ефремовой: кто куда - нареч. разг.  В разные места, в разные стороны; врассыпную.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, это присоединительная конструкция без союза. См. п.6. [здесь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120). Среди примеров есть довольно похожий:

> Мы поехали на Кавказ — к солнцу, к морю;

Ср.:
"Мы поехали на Кавказ — кто к солнцу, кто к морю."

Тире в этом случае предпочтительнее, что чувствуется по паузе, но допускается и авторская пунктуация (имеется много примеров).

Comment: Не вижу аналогии "Мы поехали на Кавказ" — законченная мысль, а  "Они пошли" — нет.

Comment: @М_Г Это может зависеть от контекста, наверное. Я нашёл контекст и теперь не уверен. В других примерах с точно такими фразами у меня сомнений не было.